# Make a SQLite3 command file executable

Tags: macos, sqlite, executable, shebang

I have a file of SQLite3 commands. For example,

```
.print "This is running in SQLite3!"
```

I want the behavior of

```
sqlite3 < commands.sql
```

when I run the following on OSX:

```
./commands.sql
```

Here's my current solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sqlite3 -init
.print "This is running in SQLite3!"
```

This works, but it also prints some unwanted lines:

```
-- Loading resources from ./process_errors.sql
Error: near line 1: unrecognized token: "#"
This is running in SQLite3!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tail -n +4 "$0" | sqlite3
exit $?

-- sql commands
select * from some_table
```

Comment: Please use [`-n`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-07/msg00002.html) and quote the `$0` expansion (to support script name/directory names with spaces in them): `tail -n +4 "${0}" | sqlite3`

Comment: (Otherwise you might get output [like this](http://cdn.ohnopub.net/cdn/binki/p/8.txt)).

Comment: Thank you, @binki. Feel free to edit answers if you want to add something.

Comment: I think that edit may have only come to 5 chars ;-). Thanks for updating the answer!

Comment: I'd add `$@` like this: `tail -n +4 "$0" | sqlite3 "$@"` so I can pass SQLite parameters, e.g: database.

Comment: Otherwise, it fails: `Error: near line 3: no such table: some_table` because of database lack.